# Is there an R function that can take time series and transform it so excel can make a stepwise chart

Tags: r, excel, survival-analysis

I am working on a project for a client that want their charts done in Excel.

One of the charts I need to do is of cumulative hazards, which I get with Survival::survfit,

My problem is that excel can't do stepwise charts, so I need to transform the data, so every timepoint occurs twice; once with the previous cumulative hazard and once with the cumulative hazard at that time-point.

It is relatively easy, but annoying and time-consuming, to do this in Excel - Is there a smart way of doing it in R?

I am a relatively new r user, and I have not been able to figure out a way to do what I want.

I have tried showing what I get and what I want below:

```
#Load survival package"
library(survival)

#Create survfit object
Survival_Function <- survfit(Surv(lung$time,
                                 lung$status == 2)~1)

#extract cumulative hazards
cumhaz <- data.frame(Survival_Function$time, Survival_Function$cumhaz)

head(cumhaz)
```

Gives me the following:

```
  Survival_Function.time Survival_Function.cumhaz
1                      5              0.004385965
2                     11              0.017601824
3                     12              0.022066110
4                     13              0.031034720
5                     15              0.035559606
6                     26              0.040105061
```

But for excel to make the charts properly I'd need it to look like this:

```
  Survival_Function.time Survival_Function.cumhaz
1                      5              0.004385965
2                     11              0.004385965
3                     11              0.017601824
4                     12              0.017601824
5                     12              0.022066110
6                     13              0.022066110
7                     13              0.031034720
8                     15              0.031034720
9                     15              0.035559606
10                    26              0.035559606
11                    26              0.040105061
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please have a look [how to make a good reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), i.e. provide an example of the data you have and the desired output format. Then it's easier to help you, thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I have tried to update the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, one simple approach is to repeat the columns, with each element repeated twice. From here, you can remove the first element from the `time` column and the last from `cumhaz` column then combine.
An example of this code is:

```
x <- data.frame(
    Time = c(1,2,3,4,5), 
    Hazard = c(6,7,8,9,10)
)

 data.frame(
     Time = rep(x$Time, each = 2)[-1], #Repeats the time, removing the first to give you the desired formatting
     Hazard = rep(x$Hazard, each = 2)[-length(rep(x$Hazard, each = 2))] # By removing the last element is means that they have the same length
)
```

and this gives you the desired output.

Note: If you have a large amount of columns this will be cumbersome, however for just two or so it should be fine.